# what is the mistake i made this program it will through runtime error?

Tags: c, data-structures

[Insert the element in last using single link list . please suggest what is the mistake i made . i shows run time error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmtxx.png)

Comment: Please use links for complementary information only (if needed). The question should be self-contained.

Comment: ...if the [mcve] guidelines in the Help Center aren't clear, consider reading through http://sscce.org/, particularly the "Tricks for Trimming" section, for guidance on how we expect a reproducer to be prepared for inclusion *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the condition check of while loop, it should be

```
while(temp->next!=NULL){
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*. Only content included *in the question itself* is considered to count towards the first bullet point ("specific details that can uniquely identify the problem"); following this rule ensures that one spends time answering questions that are searchable and remain useful to others indefinitely (instead of depending on links that can change over time, and have content that isn't indexed for search to help folks find the SO question and its linked answers only when appropriate).